# Add Late Answers & Low Quality Posts to the Review panel/blurb

Tags: feature-request, review

The panel on [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) currently looks like this:

[image]

Of the 6 queues though, there are 2 queues missing from this blurb ([Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) & [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)).

I propose changing the bullet points to:

- Evaluating new **and late** posts
- Voting to close or reopen questions
- Reviewing suggested edits **and low quality posts**

Answer (score 2):

"Late posts" aren't, they are *answers* to old questions by newcomers.

"Low quality posts" is OK, but I'm not sure I agree on placing it there.

Comment: Fundamentally though...